# In neo4j i have to create mutliple relationships between 2 nodes,but whenever a new relationship is being created I want the nodes to created again

Tags: database, csv, neo4j, graph-databases

In neo4j i have to create mutliple relationships between 2 nodes, but whenever a new relationship is being created I want the nodes to created again. for example,to create these 2 relationships between a,b

```
(a)-[r:contains{qty:1}]->(b)

(a)-[r:contains{qty:0}]->(b)
```

but there must be 4 nodes and 2 relations as a result.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created all the available nodes and the required number of copies and started matching based on their UNIQUE ids.But this is a time-taking method.I was thinking of creating a Constraint on the number of relationships a node can have as 1 so that when a extra relationship is added an extra relationship nodes would be created again